# Insert two images with a text in the center LaTeX

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I have an internship report to do, and I like to see something like that.
[image: page de garde]

what is the latex code to write to get a cover page like the following
Thank you very much in advance for any answer.

Comment: Bonjour and welcome to TeX.SX! Please note that not all of us here can speak French and that questions (and answers) should be written in English. If you want a French Q&A site, you may be interested in https://texnique.fr/

Comment: At a minimum, do tell us which document class you intend to use, what the main document font size is supposed to be, which fonts are to be used, what the page size is (A4? something else?), and how wide the margins are supposed to be. If you don't provide this information, we'll have to guess -- and the likelihood that the guesses will all be correct is pretty much negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided no information about a whole host of document parameters. E.g., what's the page size of your document, how wide are margins, which fonts are in use, what's the main document font size, etc.? Hence, the following example, which uses three side-by-side `minipage` environments, can be no more than a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % select main document font size
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set paper size and margin widths
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman font (clone)
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for "\Centering" directive
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit "demo" option in real document
\begin{document}

\noindent % <-- important
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}  % hopefully not a bad guess
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
                 height=0.667\textwidth]{image1.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}  % another guess
\Centering\bfseries

République Tunisienne

\medskip
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur et de la Recherche Scientifique

\medskip
Université de Tunis El Manar

\medskip
Institut Supérieur d'Informatique d'El Manar
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}  % yet another guess
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
                 height=0.667\textwidth]{image2.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```