# How to align two images with text in the middle

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I wanted to create some text with an image on each side like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435536/277536).
Problem is, the right side overflows the margins. How can I center this block?

This is what I have done so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % select main document font size
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % set paper size
% remove all possible margins
\geometry{top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman font (clone)
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for "\Centering" directive
\usepackage{graphicx} % omit "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{mwe} % for "\raisebox" directive
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for aligning image

% indentation is zero
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
            height=0.667\textwidth, keepaspectratio,left]{image001.jpg}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.667\linewidth}  % another guess
            \Centering
            \Large\textbf{REPUBLIKA OF ITALY}\\
            \Large\textbf{UNIVERSITETY OF PISA}\\
            \Large\textbf{RANDOM FACULTTY ETC ETC ETC}\\
            \Large\textbf{ADDITIONAL LINE}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}  % yet another guess
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
            height=0.667\textwidth,keepaspectratio,right]{image002.png}
        \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your calculations of `minipage`s width is wrong:

0.2\linwidth + 0.667\linwidth  + 0.20\linwidth = 1,067\linwidth

consequently they spill out on the right border.

Rather than `minipage`s I would use `tabularx` table, where I would left calculation of the middle column left to LateX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}       % select main document font size
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=1in,
            showframe               % remove in real doc+ument
            ]{geometry}             % set paper size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}    % Times Roman font (clone)
\usepackage{ragged2e}               % for "\Centering" directive
\usepackage{tabularx}               % for table ...
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}      % for aligning image

% indentation is zero
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=0.7\linewidth, keepaspectratio}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{0.2\linewidth}
                                >{\Centering\large\bfseries}X
                                 p{0.2\linewidth}
                                 @{} }
    \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
        &   REPUBLIKA OF ITALY          \par
            UNIVERSITETY OF PISA        \par
            RANDOM FACULTTY ETC ETC ETC \par
            ADDITIONAL LINE &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines indicate page layout)

Comment: thank you @Zarko, as soon as I wrote the question I noted the miscalculation. Thank you for the different approach with tabularx